# What is the probability of selecting 3 specific indexes of a list of 17 elements when using (int)(1+(Math.random()*16)) to select any 3 indexes

Tags: java

I have a list of 17 elements in java from where I randomly select 3 indexes using the code below and replace the values at those indexes with some given values. I would like to know what is the probability of selecting specific 3 indexes, say for example the indexes (4,9,12) when running the program one time. And how many times I should run my program (meaning selection each time 3 different indexes to be replaced) so that to maximize the chances of selecting the very specific indexes ((4,9,12) for example).
Thanks for your help.

```
public int Rand2(){
        return ((int)(1+(Math.random()*16)));
    }
```

Comment: This seems like more of a maths question that a programming question.

Comment: This is an statistics question, not a java nor algorithm one. Still the probability is (1/17)*(1/16)*(1/15)

Comment: You might want to change your expression. You need to chose `1 of 17` values. So if `x = Math.random()*16` then`0 <= x < 16`. add `1` to that and cast it to an `int` and `1 <= x < 17` or `16` values. So change 16 to 17 in your expression.

Answer (score 0):

```java
    public double prob(int arrayLength, int items){

        double a = items;
        for(int j = a-1; j > 0; j--) {
            a *= j;
        }

        double b = arrayLength - items;
        for(int i = b-1; i > 0; i--) {
            b *= i;
        }

        double c = arrayLength;
        for(int k = c-1; k > 0; k--) {
            c *= k;
        }

        return 1/(c/(a*b));
    }
```

This is a general function for the probability of selecting a certain given amount of items of an array of a given length. So for your case it would be:

```java
prob(17,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Three values of `x` are generated randomly where `1 <= x <= 17`. The total number of ordered arrangements is `17*17*17`.  Of those, a `[4,9,12]` is required.  Since order doesn't matter and there are `3!` arrangements of `[4,9,12]`, the number of possibilities is `(17*17*17)/3!` or `818.83`.  The probability is then 1/818.83 or approx. `0.0012` of generating a 4,9 and 12.

The following code bears this out.

```
      Random r = new Random();
      int count = 0;
      for (int runs = 0; runs < 1000; runs++) {
         // The following should generate about 1 hit per loop completion on 
         // average.
         for (int i = 0; i < 819; i++) {
            int a = r.nextInt(17);
            int b = r.nextInt(17);
            int c = r.nextInt(17);
            // ignore order
            if ((a == 4 && b == 9 && c == 12) || (a == 4 && b == 12 && c == 9)
                  || (a == 9 && b == 4 && c == 12)
                  || (a == 9 && b == 12 && c == 4)
                  || (a == 12 && b == 4 && c == 9)
                  || (a == 12 && b == 9 && c == 4)) {
               count++;

            }
         }
      }
      System.out.println(count + " solutions were generated.");
```